# Ставится ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли запятая после "В следующие минуты": "В следующие минуты меня толкают к стене и снова бьют".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"В следующие минуты"* - обстоятельство, а они обособляются, только если выражены деепричастием или деепричастным оборотом, которое, в свою очередь, не является фразеологизмом (сломя голову и т.п.). Следовательно, не надо никаких запятых.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. А зачем? Толкают когда? В следующие минуты, потом, после...